# 'Proptypes' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I'm setting up a new React with the help of: [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

However, I'm running into a linting issue. I'm receiving the following linting error `'PropTypes' is not defined. (no-undef)`.

Here is the code that is causing the issue:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Routers extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

...
```

I tried playing around with the [react/prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md) rule, but to no avail.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here, are you using webpack? Can you share the config..

Comment: @Purgatory I believe [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is using webpack. But I'm not using webpack separately.

Comment: Is it `'PropTypes' is not defined` or `'propTypes' is not defined`

Comment: Perhaps this issue can help? https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2528

Comment: @Purgatory `'propTypes' is not defined`. Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: I have added an answer any chance you have installed `esline v4.x` instead of using the one that is shipped with the repo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this issue [comment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2528#issuecomment-308180146).

It appears to be because you have installed `eslint 4.x` when you should just use the eslint version that is shipped with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). You should remove any eslint you have manually installed and use the one that comes with the repo.

Comment: This appeared to be the issue. I ended up running `npm run eject` to unpack the configuration of the `react-create-app` package. After this I edited the package.json to use the eslint version 3.

Comment: If you mean that you installed eslint locally in your project, this is not really supported. I know that people do this, but it is not recommend.

You don't need to install it locally, it will work out of the box. Installing it locally can mess up the versions, which is what probably happened.

Answer (score 64):

Since react 15.5, PropTypes is included in a separate package, 'prop-types'.
So this line will help

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

You can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Comment: thanks! fixed my issue.
but why have made this changes it breaks me some compiling. 
when running jest

Comment: Also we need to change React.PropTypes to PropTypes if any.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Especially since this issue is the first one showing up on Google and the issue being so trivial to encounter.
I am starting a new project, with React 17.0.2 from create-react-app. I just activated eslint in IntlliJ and my project stoped working because it wasn't compliant with this rule. It's been 3 years since PropsType was migrated so now, it's old news and newcomers like me will have this issue more and more.

Comment: For those who, like me, did not understand why propTypes is usefull in the first place : 
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: You have to run `npm i -S prop-types` in the terminal in order to work with PropTypes

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a project with eslint installed globally.
I solved this case by installing  eslint manualy in the project:
npm i eslint --save

bye
jeff

Answer (score 3):

Please Install `prop-types`

using this code:

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `<script>` tags; you can add this tag:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js" integrity="sha512-ssNhh7jlzc+K93ckIlSXFHHz6fSFv0l619WOv8xbFNRbFOujbasb42LVMOggDrQR1ScJncoWb+KAJx1uF3ipjw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can get the `minified/non-minified` and other `version` [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prop-types)

Good Luck...

Answer (score -6):

Please install the prop-types npm package - react 1.15 and greater on separate package is created.

[Here to install package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Comment: You can see above that he is already importing the separate `prop-types` package.

Comment: I do have the prop-types npm package installed.

Answer (score -6):

You can place the PropTypes just after the class (outside the class):

```
Routers.propTypes = {
   history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```