# how to change eslint 4.* to eslint 3.* in react package.json

Tags: reactjs, eslint

**Getting the 'propTypes' is not defined  no-undef**

I have found that the issue is because of ESLint version 4.* And we have to change it to ESLint version 3.* .

I have created my react app by using the create-react-app which installs the webpack , ESLint and babel by default .

I am not sure how to install the ESLint version 3.* and remove the current version .

Comment: Can you show a snippet of code that causes this error?

Comment: @btmills - It was a typo mate , i used propTypes.object instead of PropTypes.object .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to eject the app to make that change. create-react-app configuration can only be changed after you eject the app.

Comment: Yes @lavish i came across that somwhere , but am not sure how to do that  . I am just a beginner in react . I could see that the eslint is in the package-lock.json and the version is "4.10.0"

Comment: @Lars [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692537/proptypes-is-not-defined) . I could see that you have resolved the issue , can you write down the steps here . It will be of great help .