# create-react-app 'propTypes' is not defined (no-undef)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I am following the Redux Github repo's `example/todomvc` and encountered the following issue:

`[eslint] 'propTypes' is not defined. (no-undef)`

The code related to this issue,

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    addTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

 handleSave = text => {
  if (text.length !== 0) {
    this.props.addTodo(text)
  }
}
```

To reproduce the error, just

`cd example/todomvc
npm install
npm start`

And the program would be interrupted caused by compile error.

It seems to be a long unresolved issue related to `create-react-app`, I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692537/proptypes-is-not-defined) which claimed to resolve the issue by changing `eslint` version to `3.19.0`. However, `create-react-app` did ship with `eslint@3.19.0`, no need to change its version.

So what's the proper way to correct this issue ? It could be possible to:

1. change static property by using `Header.propTypes` instead of `static` syntax

However that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` at the top of your file?

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the reply. Yes, `prop-types` is imported, in fact, I happened to see this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/312) which clarifies that class static property could be parsed by `babel-eslint`@KyleRichardson